# Get screenshots of a Linux machine that I connect to remotely with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, x11, remote, putty, xforwarding

My setup is this, I connected my Cent box via PuTTY on windows 7, I've Xming and using X11forwarding to have GNOME in windows. Now when I did `gnome-screenshot` in putty, I cannot have the CentOS current Screenshot. Why is this happening? Is there any reason? Like PID is linked with screen. I get screenshot of Windows screen. I need to get CentOS screenshot, which is connected through PuTTY.
[image: The below image is a screenshot which is blank]

Comment: `$DISPLAY` probably isn't set correctly. What error messages do you get? What happens? This question is lacking information.

Comment: Q Updated @ChrisDown

Comment: Can I confirm what I think you want? You are connecting to the centos box, via ssh (putty form windows7), to get a screen-shot of that machines (contos) console (the one that maybe connected to a physical monitor). If I am correct the answer is in the first comment, however we can give more detail of how to do it if this is the case.

Comment: I would attribute this to Xming. I did something similar use X.org's X11 server on my Fedora 19 laptop and it worked fine.

Comment: It is still a problem.. :(

Comment: Does the screenshot command import -window root desktop.jpg work?